# Laravel 5: @foreach not showing results

Tags: php, laravel

Im having trouble displaying the results from my database in a `@foreach` statement in my blade file. i dont get any sort of error at all.

Controller File:

```
public function index()
    {
        /**
         * Retrieve all articles
         * where status is published [1]
         * and order them by published date decending
         *
         * @var  articles
         */

        $articles = Article::where( function($query) {
            return $query
                ->where('eHArt_Status', '1')
                ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
        });

        // return articles feed
        return view('build.4-.feeds.articles')->with('articles', $articles);
    }
```

My DB Model:

```
class Article extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'eHArticle';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        // fillable article fields
        'eHArt_OldArtID',
        'eHArt_Title',
        'eHArt_Content',
        'eHArt_Author',
        'eHArt_Status',
        'eHArt_Img',
        'published_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        // no hidden fields
    ];
}
```

My View file:

```
@section('feed')
    <!-- check if there is articles -->
    @if ( !$articles->count() )
        <p>No articles</p>
    @else
        @foreach ( $articles as $article )
            <p>Article</p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endsection
```

If i take the "!" away from the `$articles->count()` I can see the string "No articles", but my foreach doesnt display anything.

Doing a dd($articles)

```
Builder {#159 ▼
  #query: Builder {#158 ▼
    #connection: MySqlConnection {#154 ▶}
    #grammar: MySqlGrammar {#155 ▶}
    #processor: MySqlProcessor {#156}
    #bindings: array:6 [▶]
    +aggregate: null
    +columns: null
    +distinct: false
    +from: "eHArticle"
    +joins: null
    +wheres: array:1 [▶]
    +groups: null
    +havings: null
    +orders: null
    +limit: null
    +offset: null
    +unions: null
    +unionLimit: null
    +unionOffset: null
    +unionOrders: null
    +lock: null
    #backups: []
    #bindingBackups: []
    #operators: array:26 [▶]
    #useWritePdo: false
  }
  #model: Article {#152 ▼
    #table: "eHArticle"
    #fillable: array:7 [▶]
    #hidden: []
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  #eagerLoad: []
  #macros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:11 [▶]
  #scopes: []
}
```

Comment: can you do dd($articles) inside index method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a get() method after the query if you are using Builder.

```
$articles = Article::where( function($query) {
            return $query
                ->where('eHArt_Status', '1')
                ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
        })->get();
```

else you should change the query to

```
$articles = Article::where('eHArt_Status', '1')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results and https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

You need to echo it inside the `<p>` tag `{{$article}}`

```
@section('feed')
    @if(count($articles))
        @foreach ( $articles as $article )
            <h1>{{$article->eHArt_Title}}</h1>
            <p>{{$article->eHArt_Content}}</p>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No articles</p>
    @endif
@endsection
{!! $articles->render() !!}
```

Comment: This is really bad advice. First of all, the query is too redundant: `Article::where('eHArt_Status', '1')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);` is correct one. Also, using `count()` without comparison (>0, for example) is really bad practice. I wrote this for guys who will read this in future, so they could do things right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(count($articles) > 0)`:

```
@section('feed')
    <!-- check if there is articles -->
    @if(count($articles) > 0)
        @foreach ($articles as $article)
            <p>Article</p>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No articles</p>
    @endif
@endsection
```

You can read more about `count()` method in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures).

Also, you should use this query to get correct results:

```
Article::where('eHArt_Status', '1')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Still nothing. it just shows a blank page when refreshing the page. however if i change the if statement to @if(!count($articles) it displays the text "No articles"

Comment: see my answer.. @WesMurray it will work..m pretty sure

Comment: Did you use `@if(count($articles))` or `if(count($articles) > 0)`?

Comment: You should check if any result is returned ,...I suggested you do dd($articles) in index method of your controller

Comment: What should i be looking for in the dd($articles) it does return a list of information @Digitlimit

Comment: @WesMurray, copy-paste this information here or to some online code share service please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin have updated my original question with the dd results. thanks

Comment: @WesMurray, you didn't answer '>0 or not' question (3rd comment). Also, why don't you use simpler `Article::where('eHArt_Status', '1')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);`?

Comment: @WesMurray i updated my answer according to what ur dd()  says :)